# Unique slugs in MongoDB with NextJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

In my NextJS + MongoDB project, I have an API at `api/groups/new.js` that creates a new `Group` Object.

Is there a simple way to generate a unique `slug` parameter for each `Group` that's created based on the Group's `name`?

Comment: You mean you want to [generate a random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)?

Comment: @juliomalves no, more like converting a `name` of "Some Group Name" to "some-group-name" or "some-group-name-1" in the event of a naming conflict

Comment: I had that issue before, what I did is adding more field called nid based on unqiue random nano (small) id, it gonna be like this /[nid]/slug
and this exactly what most websites use you can check this questions link above